# A Problem on Symmetric Polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

**Consider the biquadratic equation $x^4+4px^3+6qx^2+4rx+s=0$. If $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3}$ and $\alpha_{4}$ are the roots of this equation find—
$\sum_{\text {symmetric}}\left(\alpha_{1}-\alpha_{2}\right)^{2}$ and $\sum_{\text {symmetric}}\left(\alpha_{1}-\alpha_{2}\right)^{4}$.**

**What is your answer for $\sum_{\text {symmetric }}\left(\alpha_{1}-\alpha_{2}\right)^{2 k}$ where $k$ is a natural number. Find also $\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{3}-\alpha_{4}\right)\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{3}-\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{4}\right)\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{4}-\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{3}\right)$.**

To be honest, I have no idea how to solve the last section, but anyways I think that an elegant application of *Newton's identities* should provide us with the solution.

I am able to solve for $\sum_{\text {symmetric}}\left(\alpha_{1}-\alpha_{2}\right)^{2}$ which comes out to be $96(p^2-q)$ by using *Vieta's relations*. But doing the same for $\sum_{\text {symmetric}}\left(\alpha_{1}-\alpha_{2}\right)^{4}$ makes it too complex.

I'm looking for an elegant solution or atleast a hint for the above problems.

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: What do you denote the *symmetric* sums exactly? The sums $\sum\limits_{1\le i<j\le 4}$?

Comment: @Bernard Yes there are only 4 roots.

Comment: Are you aware that the first expression you give is the discriminant of the equation (generalising the discriminant of a quadratic) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant ?

Comment: @Jean Marie I'm not sure if I'm able to understand you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In the reference I gave, see the two paragraphs "Degree 4" and "Expression in terms of roots".